# Failed to execute draw image to canvas in p:chart of type bar

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I want to use primefaces 6.1 to export a bar chart. Here is how I've defined the chart:

```
<p:chart type="bar" extender="myExtender" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" model="#{myBean.myModel}"  responsive="false" shadow="false" widgetVar="myChart" />
```

I am attempting to export the chart with the below code:

```
if (PF('myChart') !== undefined && PF('myChart').exportAsImage().src.startsWith('data:image')) {
    // do something with the data
}
```

When the chart is generated, it has data in the UI. However, when the exportAsImage() function executes, I see an error:

```
Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2d': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
```

I thought the issue might be timing related. However, if I create a javascript function that calls jqplotToImageElem() directly, I get the same error.

```
setTimeout(function () {PF('myChart').jq.jqplotToImageElem();}, 20000);
```

Interestingly enough, when I generate a pie chart, I do not see that error and am able to observe the exportAsImage() function working correctly. Here is my piechart code:

```
<p:chart type="pie" extender="anotherExtender" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;" responsive="true" shadow="false"  widgetVar="myPieChart" model="#{myBean.pieModel}" />
```

What must I do to be able to export a bar chart alike the pie chart using the Primefaces provided exportAsImage() function?

Comment: I've seen thiss a duplicate iirc  but cannot find it.

Comment: @Kukeltje agreed. i recall something similar in the past, but can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: [mcve] is missing...I cannot even try to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

This just works for me in the PrimeFaces showcase with PrimeFaces 8.0

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/export.xhtml